# Record Audio With Kinect

Tags: c#, audio, kinect, wav, kinect-sdk

I tried to adjust this Wav Recording sample :
http://channel9.msdn.com/Series/KinectQuickstart/Audio-Fundamentals

To the new SDK (Ver 1.6) and for some reason - the resulting .wav file is invalid

In the Init:

```
        this.audioStream = this.sensor.AudioSource.Start();

        // Use a separate thread for capturing audio because audio stream read operations
        // will block, and we don't want to block main UI thread.
        this.readingThread = new Thread(AudioReadingThread);
        this.readingThread.Start();
        fileStream = new FileStream(@"d:\temp\temp.wav", FileMode.Create);

        int rec_time = (int) 20 * 2 * 16000;//20 sec
        WriteWavHeader(fileStream, rec_time);
```

The thread:

```
    private void AudioReadingThread()
    {

        while (this.reading)
        {
                int readCount = audioStream.Read(audioBuffer, 0, audioBuffer.Length);

                fileStream.Write(audioBuffer, 0, readCount);
        }
    }
```

Wav Header:

```
    static void WriteWavHeader(Stream stream, int dataLength)
    {
        //We need to use a memory stream because the BinaryWriter will close the underlying stream when it is closed
        using (var memStream = new MemoryStream(64))
        {
            int cbFormat = 18; //sizeof(WAVEFORMATEX)
            WAVEFORMATEX format = new WAVEFORMATEX()
            {
                wFormatTag = 1,
                nChannels = 1,
                nSamplesPerSec = 16000,
                nAvgBytesPerSec = 32000,
                nBlockAlign = 2,
                wBitsPerSample = 16,
                cbSize = 0
            };

            using (var bw = new BinaryWriter(memStream))
            {
                bw.Write(dataLength + cbFormat + 4); //File size - 8
                bw.Write(cbFormat);

                //WAVEFORMATEX
                bw.Write(format.wFormatTag);
                bw.Write(format.nChannels);
                bw.Write(format.nSamplesPerSec);
                bw.Write(format.nAvgBytesPerSec);
                bw.Write(format.nBlockAlign);
                bw.Write(format.wBitsPerSample);
                bw.Write(format.cbSize);

                //data header
                bw.Write(dataLength);
                memStream.WriteTo(stream);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Is `this.audioStream` otherwise valid?  How are you setting up your sensor?

Comment: The code runs without exceptions, the sensor is set, and the wav file is not empty. Just the format is probably crooked

Comment: can you send me your resulting file? I am having some trouble setting this code up to run while trying to reach the same goal. What namespaces are the WAVEFORMATEX and WriteString classes coming from? Where exactly do i put in the riff header and modification of memstream at the data header in your code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to add the code to add the "RIFF Header" to the file. The code is as simple as:

```
//RIFF header
WriteString(memStream, "RIFF");
bw.Write(dataLength + cbFormat + 4); //File size - 8
WriteString(memStream, "WAVE");
WriteString(memStream, "fmt ");
bw.Write(cbFormat);
```

You also forgot to modify `memStream` at the "data header", you need the line:

```
WriteString(memStream, "data");
```