# recording audio with Kinect

Tags: c#, matlab, audio, kinect

relative to this post: [Record Audio With Kinect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14204902/record-audio-with-kinect) ,  I've included all the necessary headers for writing to a WAV file. Although the wav file plays ok, when I try opening it in matlab, I get the following error: "Invalid Wave File. Reason: Incorrect chunk size information in WAV file.". Something is obviously messed up with the headers, but I can't figure out what. Should I probably try using NAudio for writing the byte stream to a wav file?

Comment: The error message saying something about the header, Matlab wavread need to know Frequency and stuff like that, be sure it there.

Comment: Can you please post the MATLAB code too?

Comment: I just type:  wavread('kinectAudio.wav') . I think Alenxandre confuses wavread with wavwrite... Check out wavread here: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/wavread.html;jsessionid=23e446ebcd9f82228b55fe60e4f9